# Using razor syntax in Ember App.js ajax call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to write my first `Ember` app and not sure at all what I'm doing. I am doing this in an ASP MVC 4 project and I want to be able to click the "Agent" menu tab, and have Ember grab the relevant information from the `Agent` controller.

When I think I have this set up properly, because when I click on the "Agent" menu item I get the following error:

"Error while loading route"

Again, this is my first attempt at Ember, so I would assume that means the ajax call is being attempted, so I've routed this properly but the Razor syntax is not being translated properly.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('home', { path: "/Index" });
    this.resource('agents', { path: "/Agents" });
    this.resource('topics',  function() {
        this.resource('topic', {path: '/topic/:topic_id'})
    });  
    this.resource('contacts', { path: "/Contacts" });
});

App.AgentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.Store.all();
    }
})

App.Store.reopenClass({
    all: function () {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: {id: '1'},
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAgentData", "Agent")',
            sucess: function (data) {
                return data;
            }            
        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Per request here is the handlebars code from my `layout.cshtml` page.

```
                <nav>
                    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
                        <div class="navbar">
                            <div class="navbar-inner">                                
                            <ul id="menu">
                                <li>{{#linkTo 'home'}}Home{{/linkTo}}</li>
                                <li>{{#linkTo 'agents'}}Agents{{/linkTo}}</li>
                                <li>{{#linkTo 'topics'}}About{{/linkTo}}</li>
                                <li>{{#linkTo 'contacts'}}Contact{{/linkTo}}</li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{outlet}}
                    </script>
                </nav>
```

Comment: can you show your handlebars/template code where the link is that is failing?

Comment: just added to the post.